# How to terminate the old request and initiate new API call in php?

Tags: php

I need to generate and save large amount of string data in to a `.js` file, the string generate from a mySQL table and its size is 7000+ rows, so the for loop take  more than a minutes to complete the for loop.
And if I call the same API, before finished the for loop execution, both loop are execute.

**Examples**

1. Step 1 - Called the `abc.php` => executing the for loop (Not finished)
2. Step 2 - Before stop, the above for loop, refresh the `abc.php` code **or** call it again. Executing two for loops eg) Step 1 started for loop and Step 2 for loops are executing.

**My Idea:**
I have the plan to terminate the process, before start execute the for loop.

I have tried `flush()` and `ob_flush()`

**My code is:**

```
$run_query = mysqli_query($dbcon,$qry_select);
$rows = array();

while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run_query))
{
    $rows[] = $r;
}

$additional="";
for($i = 0; $i < count($rows); $i++)
{
    // You may want not to write to the file every time to minimize changes of being writing the file 
    // at the same time your ajax page is fetching it, i'll let it to you...
    $softwarecode = $rows[$i]['softwarecode'];
    $index = $rows[$i]['index1'];
    $key = $rows[$i]['key1'];
    $description = $rows[$i]['description'];
    $groupname = $rows[$i]['groupname'];

    $additional = $additional . 'var obj=new Object();' . PHP_EOL
        .'obj.softwarecode=' . $softwarecode . '; ' . PHP_EOL
        .'obj.index=' . $index . '; ' . PHP_EOL 
        .'obj.key="' . $key . '"; ' . PHP_EOL 
        .'obj.description="' . $description . '";' . PHP_EOL 
        .'obj.groupname="' . $groupname . '";' . PHP_EOL 
        .'_json_shortcutmenu.push(obj);' . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution won't kill the old process, but stop the new one from running if it finds one already running. If the old process is close to completion, by not running a new one you'd save cpu cycles and also user's time

This solution involves Semaphore, which is essentially a "token" that the process tries to acquire before starting to run. If the process finds the token already taken, it implies there is an existing process running...

```
//Semaphore properties
$key = 123456;
$max = 1;
$permissions = 0666;
$autoRelease = 1;
semaphore = sem_get($key, $max, $permissions, $autoRelease);
if(!$semaphore) {
     die("Failed on sem_get()");
}
if (!sem_acquire($semaphore, true)) {
    // Previous process is still executing.
    return "Previous process running, please wait";
}

// Your long running processing starts now .... 
$run_query = mysqli_query($dbcon,$qry_select);
$rows = array();

while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run_query))
{
    $rows[] = $r;
}

$additional="";
for($i = 0; $i < count($rows); $i++)
{
    // You may want not to write to the file every time to minimize changes of being writing the file 
    // at the same time your ajax page is fetching it, i'll let it to you...
    $softwarecode = $rows[$i]['softwarecode'];
    $index = $rows[$i]['index1'];
    $key = $rows[$i]['key1'];
    $description = $rows[$i]['description'];
    $groupname = $rows[$i]['groupname'];

    $additional = $additional . 'var obj=new Object();' . PHP_EOL
        .'obj.softwarecode=' . $softwarecode . '; ' . PHP_EOL
        .'obj.index=' . $index . '; ' . PHP_EOL 
        .'obj.key="' . $key . '"; ' . PHP_EOL 
        .'obj.description="' . $description . '";' . PHP_EOL 
        .'obj.groupname="' . $groupname . '";' . PHP_EOL 
        .'_json_shortcutmenu.push(obj);' . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
}

// Release the Semaphore for the next process....
sem_release($semaphore);
```

Another solution would be not letting your JavaScript to send a second request while the first one is still in process - you can disable the "submit" button and show some spinning wheel etc.